# accessing property from another viewController's class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, instance-variables

Working with a split view controller...I have a variable that gets a value in my settingsViewController class, and now in my main view controller I need to access the valuable that variable.  How can I get to settingsViewController.selectedCounty?

```
class settingsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

 let titleData = TitleData()
 var selectedCounty = String?("Allegany")
```

trying to grab this value to place in:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


let settings = settingsViewController()
let selectedCounty = settings.selectedCounty
```

returns "settingsViewController.type" does not have a member named selectedCounty?

[image]

Comment: Think about it: `let settings = settingsViewController()` creates a *new* instance of the settingsViewController class, which is completely *unrelated* to the existing settingsViewController instance.

Comment: How do settingsViewController and main view controller fit in with the split view controller?

Comment: MartinR I understand what you're saying and it seemed weird to me too, but why is that if I create a new Swift file "MyNewClass" that includes variable X, then make an instance of MYNewClass via myNewClass = MyNewClass(), I am able to call myNewClass.x?  In other words a custom class I can call, but I cant call my settingsViewController class because it inhereits from ViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar I added a screen shot

Comment: The screen shot is not that helpful, I still can't really tell what you're doing. It looks like the navigation controller that houses ViewController is one of the children of the split view controller, but which? Is it the detail or the master? I don't see another relationship segue from the split view controller. There should be 2; one to the master and one to the detail. The segue to settings from the split view looks like a "Show" segue. Why is that? And you also have another "Show" from ViewController to settings, so this is a strange setup if I'm reading it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, I needed to call prepareForSegue on settingsViewController to be able to pass this to my other ViewController (note I changed it to FirstViewController to avoid confusion:

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController: FirstViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FirstViewController
    destViewController.selectedCounty = selectedCounty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift initial value of a (stored)property can not be dependent on other property(s). 
Here your `ViewController`'s property(i.e. `selectedCounty`) depends on `settingsViewController`'s property(i.e. `selectedCounty`).

**Solution:**
You can assign it later in `init()`

```
let selectedCounty:String

init(){

selectedCounty = settings.selectedCounty!

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
let settings = settingsViewController()
```

creates a constant of the name `settings` of type `settingsViewController`. Then in the line

```
let selectedCounty = settingsViewController.selectedCounty
```

this constant is not accessed. Rather a type property `selectedCounty` of the type `settingsViewController` is accessed. Since there is no such type property, this is an error.

Access the property as follows:

```
let selectedCounty = settings.selectedCounty
```

or make it a type property:

Comment: Sorry I typed my code wrong, I had it the way you suggested:  settings.selectedCounty but get same error